# Simple but accurate benchmarking of C / C++ code

Tags: c++, c, benchmarking

What is a recommended methodology / library for accurate benchmarking of C / C++ code? Something that would overcome the inaccuracies of simply measuring execution time, i.e. that CPU frequency and system load may change across execution times. Not sure if counting executed instructions is the correct approach, because the bottleneck in my code will (probably) be memory access.

Comment: What is C / C++ code?

Comment: Note that changing CPU frequency with constant memory frequency means memory is a bigger bottleneck when your CPU is clocked higher.  e.g. an L3 cache miss at power-saving 1GHz might be 100 core clock cycles, but 400 core clock cycles at 4GHz max turbo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNU profiler, gprof, is a traditional way of doing performance measurements for a signle-threaded code. You do not have to instrument the code manually, just add an option to gcc during build.

Comment: gprof could not be used when you have libraries which doesn't compile with -p (gprof enable), so library functions could doesn't count accurately in benchmarks

Comment: @e.jahandar Yes, only the top-level function calls to the library will be benchmarked. But if you don't have the source code of the lib, you typically do not care about the lower level functions either. In fact, system calls and multithreading give more trouble.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on X86, you can try Intel V-Tune Amplifier, it gave you deep micro architecture analysis of C or C++ application. It uses CPU builtin performance counters for measuring execution time and also number cache misses and lots of micro architecture level information's.

Comment: Other programs can use the same hardware performance counters.  e.g. on Linux `perf stat ./myprogram` will measure a default set of counters over the whole program.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is close to impossible.

Because on modern processors the execution time is highly indeterministic due to cache and virtual memory effects. In addition, the number of cycles of some operations depends on the particular values of the arguments.

This means that static benchmarking (just looking at the source code) cannot be accurate and you can't avoid running the program. Then the running time will fluctuate from one execution to the next.

Even taking an average of several runs is inaccurate, as the second and next executions will be influenced by the first and won't be in realistic conditions anymore.

Actually, "the" running time doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: The running time of a program without user input (my case) could be defined in a probabilistic way. Given an *environment* (system state before execution, stream of input events) the running time is approximately deterministic. So the running time can be defined as the expected running time assuming a random environment chosen from a suitable distribution.

Comment: Problem with simple benchmarking is that we don't know if an improvement in measured execution time is the result of different environment or of the modified program. Averaging helps but only to some extent. What I was looking for was minimizing the effect of the random enironment (such as CPU frequency).

Comment: The CPU frequency is about the only parameter which is perfectly non-random!

Comment: The OS changes the CPU frequency changes quite often, at least on my laptop.

Comment: @fhucho: you can inhibit this.

Answer (score -1):

Use tick and tock on clock(), and run for at least a tenth of a second by wrapping the functions in a for loop. That eliminates most of the caching effects. However a point you can make is that you don't necessarily want to eliminate caching because the function will be run in a partially-cached context when used for real. It's hard to answer that one.